# iOS config ip Subnet Mask router programmatically

Tags: ios, wifi

I have an ip-camera connecting to a wifi router.  My App can receive video stream from the camera when iPhone connects to the same wifi hotspot.

In iOS 11, I use [NEHotspotConfigurationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager?language=objc) to connect to the wifi hotspot programmatically.

In addition, I hope iPhone can use cellular data when connecting to wifi. Then i find [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/can-i-connect-to-wifi-but-still-use-cellular) .It work pretty well, but user must leave the app and complete the configuration in the setting page.

So, is there any way to config iPhone ip、 subnet mask、 and router programmatically.

Comment: You cannot modify the network configuration programmatically.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks for your comment.  I did this by change the DHCP configuration of my WiFi router.  The only thing need to do is setting the gateway of DHCP service to empty.